# Condition statement on language

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement

Can I set condition on language such as:

```
IF(statement is in Hebrew) 
.....
ELSE IF(statement in English)
......
ELSE
......
```

Or is there other way to achieve the same result?

Comment: What woupd happen in these cases? Please give full example

Comment: You could do this logic in SQL however wouldn't you want to do it at the application layer?

Comment: I think I hadn't clarified it well. Say I have variable "@string" of type NVARCHAR(MAX). I want to check the string contained in "@string" and if the string is in English execute one batch of code, if the string in "@string" is in Hebrew execute another batch.

Comment: Is "42" Elbonian? What do you trust to intuit the language(s) of a string?

Comment: Then update the question to @string

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't have any built-in functions for determining what language a string is in.

If you choose to write your own function, then employing it in the IF structure you want is simple:

```
IF dbo.GetLanguage(statement) = 'Hebrew'
 ...
ELSE IF dbo.GetLanguage(statement) = 'English'
 ...
ELSE
```